# How to redirect https to subdomain?

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7.5, subdomain, http-redirect

I want to redirect both http://www.mysite.com and https://www.mysite.com to https://secure.mysite.com under IIS7.5.

I've installed the `HTTP Redirect` module, which seems to work fine for http:// redirect, by setting up a site binding to http and a HTTP redirect to ([exact site](https://secure.mysite.com.))

But how do I redirect https://www.mysite.com to https://secure.mysite.com?

If I set up a `HTTPS` binding for the website it seems to bind to **www.mysite.com** automatically, even though the `SSL` certificate is for **secure.mysite.com**, and there doesn't seem to be any way to split the two.

Ideally I'd like to do this via `IIS` configuration rather than code..

Comment: How about using the [url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) instead?

Comment: I'll take a look. But I see other users reporting a number of issues after installing it, so was hoping to be able to do this with a simple IIS setting. Alternatively I could probably just do this in code (since my website is running asp.net anyway).